# What happened to immortal item of Dota 2's sixth compendium goal?

Tags: dota-2

The compendium says that users will receive an immortal item after the compendium reaches the sixth goal, but it looks like we haven't received it yet. Does anyone know if it is delayed, or are some people just not getting it for some reason?

Comment: Most likely a delay, I've had stretch goals from pre-orders take awhile to end up in my inventory on several occasions.

Comment: @GeoStrike, you should change your selection to the currently true answer.

Comment: well I spent more than 5 minutes (really) to make a decision. All the answers were right at the time they have answered. I am not sure if i have justified. I have accepted first Costa's answer and  I upvoted Ullallulloo answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No one has it yet. It hasn't been announced yet. They needed to wait to confirm that the goal would actually be reached first before working on it, and now that it has, it'll probably come in one one of the next couple of updates. My guess is the last one right before TI3, but like I said, that's just a guess. Stay tuned.

Answer (score 6):

It just took a while is all. It was finally added in the [July 26th, 2013 update](http://store.steampowered.com/news/11162/). All players who bought a Compendium should now get a copy of 
[The Immortal Reliquary](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/The%20Immortal%20Reliquary), which will give a random Immortal item out of five newly-created items when used.

The possible items seem to be:

- [Whalehook](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Whalehook), a Pudge hook
- [Scree'auk's Talon](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Scree%27auk%27s%20Talon), a Vengeful Spirit blade
- [Mace of the Chosen](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Mace%20of%20the%20Chosen), an Abaddon mace
- [Cauldron of Xahryx](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Cauldron%20of%20Xahryx), a Lone Druid cauldron
- [Leviathan Whale Blade](http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/Leviathan%20Whale%20Blade), a Kunkka sword

Answer (score 1):

Actually, no, I got a Vengeful Spirit weapon as my immortal; so it seems there is a pool of random items.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [gaming.se]! Your answer is a bit off the mark, you should look at the [faq] to see how you can make it more precise and applicable to the question being asked. ;)

Answer (score -1):

I just picked up Cauldron of Xahryx. Cauldron that sits on Lone Druids back, smoke pouring out the top. Sucks I don't play LD. Pretty sure it was the immortal gift, came in a box matching International colour schemes (like the compendium). And because I feel Valve are lazy with these kinds of things, everyone will probably get that, rather than a random item from a pool of new immortals.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Arqade! Your answer is a bit off the mark, you should look at the faq to see how you can make it more precise and applicable to the question being asked. ;)